# Simple HTML DOM Parser. Remove first row in table and then remove second column of each

Tags: php, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse an HTML string which is a table. I managed to remove the first row of the table. How can I then remove the second column in the table?

I remove the first row like this:

```
$preparsed = "<div style='border:1px #CCCCCC dotted; padding:5px'><div style=''>
              <div id='divPrint'>         
                  <table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' width='886'>
                  <tr bgcolor='#666666' class='normal' style='color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;'>
                      <td width='100px' style='font-size:11px;'><b>Type</b></td>
                      <td width='110px' style='font-size:12px;'><b>Date</b></td>
                      <td width='100px' style='font-size:12px;'><b>Details</b></td>
                      <td width='140px' style='font-size:12px;'><b>Instructor</b></td>
                      <td width='140px' style='font-size:12px;'><b>Student / Client</b></td>
                      <td style='font-size:12px;'><b>Comment</b></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class='normal' style='font-size:11px' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>Training</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>2016-10-05 <br /><i class='small'>(16:00:00-18:00:00)</i></td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>Zara</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>Gary</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>Alfred</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'></td>
                   </tr><tr class='normal' style='font-size:11px' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>Training</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>2016-10-05 <br /><i class='small'>(12:00:00-15:00:00)</i></td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>Zara</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>Gary</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'>shawn</td>
                    <td style='font-size:12px;'></td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              </div></div>";

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($preparsed);
$rows = array_slice($html->find('tr'), 1);
foreach ( $rows as $element ) {
echo '<h3>'. $element->plaintext . '</h3>';
```

This removes the first row. How can I either a)First remove every second column in each row (the date), or b) remove the first row first and then remove all the second columns in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($preparsed);
$rows = array_slice($html->find('tr'), 1);
foreach ( $rows as $element ) {
    echo '<h3>'. $element->plaintext . '</h3>';
    $cols = array_slice($element->find('td'), 2);
    foreach ( $cols as $col ) {
        echo '<h4>The second col os the row values '. $col->plaintext . '</h4>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I see I had to use array_slice for the the $cols too. Thanks a lot.