# How to remove first and last <tr> tag from table - Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

Looks like I need to use `$e->first_child ()` and `$e->lastChild ()`, but its not working.

```
require_once '/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com');

$table = $html->find('table');
echo $table->first_child();

<table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple HTML DOM Parser. Remove first row in table and then remove second column of each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899298/simple-html-dom-parser-remove-first-row-in-table-and-then-remove-second-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
$table->find('tr',0);//first one
$table->find('tr',-1);//last one
```

if not works:

```
$html->find('tr',0);//first one
$html->find('tr',-1);//last one
```

Comment: and how to echo last <td> in every <tr>?

Comment: why its not working? can it be because of not valid html markup? `foreach ($table->find('tr') as $trs) {
    $tds = $trs->find('td',-1);
    $tds->outertext = '';
    }` @michal

Comment: instead outertext use innertext. You want to replace existng text with '' correct ?